# Cant login after Ubuntu upgrade 16.04 --> 18.04

Tags: 16.04, 18.04

I can SSH into the machine as the user I'm trying to log in with, but I cant log into the GUI. So I did apt-get update && apt-get full-upgrade on it, but I still cant log in. I deleted .Xauthority and .cache, I also install gnome DE and tried to log in with that but still no go. Any other ideas please?

Comment: what happens when you try to login?

Comment: It goes to a black screen for a few seconds, then takes me back to the login screen again, sorry forgot to say that.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Just had to apt-get purge NVIDIA*
I don't know why, I don't even have an NVIDIA card on the machine.